# Why does spam get an upvote?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/42145/do-you-know-any-interesting-chess-location-around-the-world) was pretty clearly spam. And yet, based on users reputation (5 currently) and this being there only post, there must of been an upvote? Why? Spam shouldn't get upvotes? I know it will get deleted, but it is still confusing to me who is upvoting spam? This isn't the first time I've seen this either.

Comment: "*Why does spam get an upvote?*" because human is unpredictable, or they don't think it's spam.

Comment: turns out i was the one who upvoted this. actually i found the website interesting. maybe OP should've presented it in a different way, as a Q and self Answer to make it like sharing a resource? idk

Answer (score 3):

Possible explanations:

- the reputation increase came from an upvote on a different, now-deleted post. Indeed, reputation gained from deleted posts is [not always](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320459/why-are-reputation-points-lost-for-deleted-questions) rolled back.
- the spammer created two accounts, and upvoted one from the other.
- someone misclicked. Ultimately, as with drive-by downvotes, there is little point in psychoanalyzing this: there is a button on their interface, and people will click on it for all the wrong reasons in the world.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Apparently under some conditions deleted posts can give a permanent rep increase: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31177/65548 , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320459/why-are-reputation-points-lost-for-deleted-questions